# Include file PDF in folders with accents in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I've tried several ways to include a PDF file using PHP on Linux, it works normally on Windows, but not on Linux.

I have several directories with accents and I need to include PDF files that are inside the directories.

I pass the name of the PDF files and include the PDF.

My problem is with the encoding and accentuation of the folders. The files doesn't have accents, only the folders.

Examples of folders / files:

- files/ño/hash1.pdf
- files/nó/hash2.pdf
- files/ção/hash.pdf

  ```
   function getFileInContents($dir, $filename)
   {
       $files = scandir($dir);

       foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
           $path = realpath($dir . '/' . $value);

           if (!is_dir($path)) {
               if ($filename == $value) {
                   return $path;
               }
           } elseif ($value != "." && $value != "..") {
               getFileInContents($path, $filename);
           }
       }

       return null;
   }

   if (!isset($_GET['f'])) {
       echo 'File not found';
       exit;
   }

   $local = 'files/';
   $path = getFileInContents($local, $_GET['f']);

   if (!$path) {
       echo 'File not found';
       exit;
   }

   $mime = mime_content_type($path);
   header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
   include_once($path);
  ```

Comment: That depends on the file system, so it's not a PHP or PDF related question, but connected to operating system / file system.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I don't have access to know the file system, but OS is Linux.

Comment: Don't use `include` on a file that is not a PHP script! You should use [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Also, is this really related to PDF itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer adds on and expounds on the one offered up by @James, because you have additional issues:

1. As pointed out in the comment made by @Olivier, you should be using `readfile()` instead of `include`.
2. You should not include the final '/' in your declaration of `$local` since you will be concatenating a '/' to the passed *$dir* argument in function `getFileInContents`.
3. Presumably function `getFileInContents` is intended to recursively search subdirectories, but it is not doing this correctly; it only is searching the first subdirectory it finds and if the sought file is not present in that subdirectory it returns with a "not found" condition and never searches any other subdirectories that might be present in the directory.

```
function getFileInContents($dir, $filename)
{
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . '/' . $value);

        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            if ($filename == $value) {
                return $path;
            }
        } elseif ($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            $new_path = getFileInContents($path, $filename);
            if ($new_path) {
                return $new_path;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

if (!isset($_GET['f'])) {
    echo 'File not found';
    exit;
}

$local = 'files';
$path = getFileInContents($local, $_GET['f']);

if (!$path) {
    echo 'File not found';
    exit;
}

$mime = mime_content_type($path);
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
readfile($path);
```

Comment: This 3 points solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the problem is anything to do with the folder names. I think the problem is that your recursive function is not actually returning the value when it finds the file.

When you call `getFileInContents($path, $filename);` you then need to return the value, if it's not null, to break the loop.

```
function getFileInContents($dir, $filename)
{
    $files = scandir($dir);
    
    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . '/' . $value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            if ($filename == $value) {
                return $path;
            }
        } elseif ($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            $testValue = getFileInContents($path, $filename);
            if ($testValue!=null){
                return $testValue;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the question. In windows and macOS this code works very well, but in linux doesn't.

Comment: I just tested it on linux. I think the only reason you're seeing the issue is the folder sorting. Please try my code and see if this fixes it for you.

Comment: @James There may be several issues, but your original code definitely can't work for files that are inside sub-directories.

Comment: @James I tried and I appreciated the anwser.